# How to interpret the preposition "from" in "risks from flooding" — what changes?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

In the headline (source NY Times):

"Read the Climate Forward Newsletter

We explain the factors that sharply increased the risks from flooding."

"from flooding" always confuses me. I don't know whether it is talking about risks when flood hit (meaning what disgrace can come when flood happen), once it is already flooded hence from. Or wheter it is talking about the risk of a flood happen.

Comment: Please edit your question to include more context, like about 100 words before this line, and a link to the article, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You will come across two phrases in this context, **the risk(s) of flooding** and **the risks (arising) from flooding**.

The **risk(s) of flooding**  refers to the probability that flooding will occur, whether as a result of heavy rain, dam bursts, the nature of the environment, lack of flood protection or similar.

The **risks from flooding** refers to the risks that will arise in the event that flooding occurs, typically the danger to people and animals and damage to property. There are also risks to transport and communication links in the event of severe flooding.

Comment: In the UK we rarely talk about the "risks from something" - and tend to express the "risks of something".  Of course the long form of "the risks arising from something" is normal with us too. But prepositions are in general a big area of idiomatic divergence between British and American English.